# Can you train a custom classifier?

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

There is some documentation on the IBM site related to visual recognition which is confusing me https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/customizing.shtml

It states:
Because custom classifiers are trained with only the images provided in a single call, you cannot update an existing classifier, you can only create new classifiers or delete existing classifiers.

But in the next section:
You can update an existing classifier by adding new classes, or by adding new images to existing classes. To update the existing classifier, use several compressed (.zip) files, including files containing positive or negative images (.jpg, or .png). You must supply at least one compressed file, with additional positive or negative examples.

So is it possible to update a custom made classifier?  I'm having issues at the moment trying to do this, but it is possibly due to me being on the trial version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can "retrain" or update a custom classifier by providing additional training data.  The conflict in the documentation will be corrected soon, thank you for pointing it out. The first quote was left in by mistake from the first version of the API.  The second section is the correct description.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is most likely to be a historic documentation problem. When it was first released it was not possible to update classifiers, but this was changed on a subsequent release.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can retrain it but in standard version only not in free version.